# How does coreos compare to triton?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rkt, triton

Recently some alternatives for running docker containers or even the app container have developed.

I know that there is rkt from coreos (https://coreos.com/blog/rocket/) and triton from joyent (https://www.joyent.com/)

How do these two approaches compare?

## Edit

Maybe I should re-phrase my question after these good comments from @ Lakatos Gyula

**How does Triton compare to coreos or kubernetes for running docker-containers at scale?**

Comment: Rkt itself is a container runtime like docker. CoreOS is the thing you are looking for I guess. I used CoreOS once, it was great but hard to set up correctly if you are new to it. (It was a small cluster only for 4-5 VMs running like 10 docker containers.) Once you learn a bit about it it's easy to use and worked fine for me.

Comment: But here (https://github.com/coreos/rkt) they market it as: rkt is an App Container runtime for Linux

Comment: Triton and CoreOS is an infrastructure to run containers in a GRID while docker and rkt is a container runtime to run a single or more container on ONE host machine.

Comment: Rkt is very similar to docker except it focuses strictly on containers and it's a reference implementation for the app container specification.

Comment: Ok. Did I understand correctly that out of the three (Docker, Coreos, Trition), Triton is the one most focused on security?

Comment: In what way is Trition different to the other two approaches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So in a way, this is an apples to oranges to grapes comparison.  CoreOS is an operating system, Kubernetes is open source container orchestration software, and Triton is a PaaS.

So CoreOS, it's a minimal operating system with a focus on security.  I've been using this in production for several months now at work, haven't found a reason to not like it yet.  It does not have a package manager, but it comes preinstalled with both rkt and Docker.  You can run both docker and rkt just fine on there.  It also comes with Etcd, which is a distributed key-value store, and it happens that kubernetes is backed by it.  It also comes with Flannel which is a networking program for networking between containers and machines in your cluster.  CoreOS also ships with Fleet, which you can think of like a distributed version of systemd, which systemd is CoreOS' init system.  And as of recently, CoreOS ships with Kubernetes itself.

Kubernetes is a container orchestration software that is made up of a few main components.  There are masters, which use the APIServer, controller and scheduler to manage the cluster.  And there are nodes which use the "kubelet" and kube-proxy".  Through these components, Kubernetes schedules and manages where to run your containers on your cluster.  As of v1.1 Kubernetes also can auto-scale your containers.  I also have been using this in production as long as I have been using CoreOS, and the two go together very well.

Triton is Joyent's Paas for Docker. Think of it like Joyent's traditional service, but instead of BSD jails (similar concept to Linux containers) and at one point Solaris Zones (could be wrong on that one, that was just something I heard from word of mouth), you're using Docker containers.  This does abstract away a lot of the work you'd have to do with setting up CoreOS and Kubernetes, that said there are services that'll do the same and use kubernetes under the hood.  Now I haven't used Triton like I have used Kubernetes and CoreOS, but it definitely seems to be quite well engineered.

Ultimately, I'd say it's about your needs.  Do you need flexibility and visibility, then something like CoreOS makes sense, particularly with Kubernetes.  If you want that abstracted away and have these things handled for you, I'd say Triton makes sense.